# Spring Boot Kafka with manual ack

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

Referring to [Spring kafka doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/htmlsingle/#kafka-listener-annotation), I am trying to implement a spring boot application which listens to a kafka topic and acks manually.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class TestApplication {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(TestApplication.class, args);
  }

  @KafkaListener(topics = "sample_log", containerFactory = "kafkaManualAckListenerContainerFactory")
  public void listen(ConsumerRecord<?, ?> cr, Acknowledgment ack) throws Exception {
      process(cr);
      ack.acknowledge();
  }
}
```

But when I ran the application, it shows:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************
Description:
A component required a bean named 'kafkaManualAckListenerContainerFactory' that could not be found.
Action:
Consider defining a bean named 'kafkaManualAckListenerContainerFactory' in your configuration.
```

As far as I'm concerned, Spring Kafka may have defined `kafkaManualAckListenerContainerFactory` bean since it is a provided feature. How could I fix the error WITHOUT manually define the bean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don’t need that `containerFactory = "kafkaManualAckListenerContainerFactory"` configuration. Just remove it altogether and rely on the provided by Spring Boot auto-configuration for Kafka: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.1.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-kafka

Comment: Thanks @artem-bilan.  I added `spring.kafka.listener.ack-mode=MANUAL_IMMEDIATE` to `application.properties`, and it works fine.